# How to make skslider autoslide true and false on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I have an skslider

```
jQuery('#slider').skdslider({
    delay:3000,
    animationSpeed: 500,
    showNextPrev:true   ,
    showPlayButton:true,
    showNav:false,
    autoSlide:false,
    animationType:'fading'
});
```

I want to start autoslide on button click. and stop the same on another button click. This to be continue. any suggestion?
is there a way like setAttribute(autoSlide)?

Answer (score 0):

Set counter on your button click and call your slider as per that counter setting.

```
  let Flag = true;
  $('button').click(function() {
    if (Flag) {
      sliderSeeting(Flag)
      Flag = false;
    } else {
      sliderSeeting(Flag)
      Flag  = true;
    }
  });
```

And your slider function:

```
function sliderSeeting(Flag) {
    jQuery('#slider').html('');
    jQuery('#slider').skdslider({
    delay:3000,
    animationSpeed: 500,
    showNextPrev:true   ,
    showPlayButton:true,
    showNav:false,
    autoSlide:Flag,
    animationType:'fading'
});
}
```

Comment: alerted flag on the function. the autoslide doesnt stop though flag is false

Comment: You need to create new instance for skdslider so clear your `slider` html  before reinitialize it.  See Updated answer.